# How to get the latest gVim on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, repository, vim, appimage

I would like to create a gVim AppImage using packages from 14.04 (why not 16.04? Because 16.04 packages are too new as AppImages will only run on distributions newer or the same age as the distribution who's packages they're built from). Now I would like my gVim AppImage to be for the very latest version of gVim, so I need a repository for 14.04 that provides the very latest gVim. I have searched Launchpad for Vim PPAs that are maintained and have not found any (all the ones I found are out-of-date).

My questions:

- I know I can build the latest gVim as a Debian package with checkinstall, but I want to use gVim from a package repository to build my gVim AppImage as it makes things a lot simpler. *Where can I find a recent Debian package of gVim?*
- Alternatively, how can I build an AppImage container from an arbitrary set of binaries (downloaded somewhere or compiled from source)?

Comment: Maybe https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim, though I have not tried it yet

Comment: Does that repository provide gvim or just vim?

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate because the other question is about any version more frequent than 7.4.338, I am more specific saying I want the **latest** version of gVim.

Comment: The latest varies with time. That's not specific at all.

Comment: Precisely, a repository that is up-to-date and maintained. Otherwise it couldn't even pretend to provide the latest version.

Comment: It could pretend to do so now, and fail two weeks from now. pi-rho's PPA was good for two years. Maybe jonathanf's PPA would last that long as well. :shrug:

Comment: None of the answers at the other question provided gVim and are presently up-to-date. Your answer, jonathonf/vim, provides Vim not gVim.

Comment: Nonsense. https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim/+build/11088283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AppImage is basically just a self-mounting filesystem image that contains the application and everything it needs to run in a single file.

Here is an example that builds GNU Emacs on Travis CI and packages it as an AppImage: https://github.com/probonopd/Emacs.AppImage

You should be able to to the same for gVim.

1. **Gather suitable binaries.** If the application has already been compiled, you can use existing binaries (for example, contained in .tar.gz, deb, or rpm archives). Note that the binaries must not be compiled on newer distributions than the ones you are targeting. In other words, if you are targeting Ubuntu 9.10, you should not use binaries compiled on Ubuntu 10.04. For upstream projects, it might be advantageous to compile special builds for use in AppImages, which is what I would recommend in this case. See the GNU Emacs example above. (For re-using existing binaries, see https://github.com/probonopd/AppImages/tree/master/recipes/meta instead.)
2. **Gather suitable binaries of all dependencies that are not part of the base operating systems you are targeting**. For example, if you are targeting Ubuntu, Fedora, and openSUSE, then you need to gather all libraries and other dependencies that your app requires to run that are not part of Ubuntu, Fedora, and openSUSE in the default installation.
3. **Create a working AppDir** from your binaries. A working AppImage runs your app when you execute its AppRun file. Again, see the GNU Emacs example linked above.
4. **Turn your AppDir into an AppImage.** This compresses the contents of your AppDir into a single, self-mounting and self-executable file. The example above uses the generate_type2_appimage function from functions.sh for this.
5. **Test your AppImage** on all base operating systems you are targeting. This is an important step which you should not skip. Subtle differences in distributions make this a must. While it is possible in most cases to create AppImages that run on various distributions, this does not come automatically, but requires careful hand-tuning.

This sounds more complicated than it actually is, all the steps besides the testing can be done on one small bash script like in the example. As you can see at https://github.com/probonopd/Emacs.AppImage, it is easy to produce an AppImage.

I recommend to work together with the upstream authors of the software, so that the upstream project themselves will provide an official AppImage. This way, the upstream project can control the end-to-end user experience of their software; something many upstream application projects appreciate. Users also can be assured that the AppImage is put together exactly in the way the original authors of the software intended and not changed in some way by intermediaries.

Comment: This doesn't address the question "where do I get the latest gVim?"

Comment: @terdon: I agree that we can assume it answers *a* question of OP but not necessarily the one they posted here. Revisiting the situation I think it would be better to edit the question post so that it (only) includes the questions that OP appears to have an actual interest in.

Comment: @DavidFoerster the question starts with "I would like to create a gVim AppImage using packages from 14.04" and I think I have answered the question in the best possible way, since using packages from 14.04 is not the best way to produce this AppImage. Hence I am surprised by the down vote.

Comment: @probono: I edited the question to fit your answer explicitly since that seems to be what OP actually cared about. Alas I can't revert my vote until your answer was edited. If you find something (even minor) to improve, make the edit, ping me and I'll convert the vote.